# Frequency out of range message when using console

Tags: graphics, monitor, virtual-console

Why does an error message appear when I switch to a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
135k / 91 hz  Frequency is out of range
```

And more importantly, how do I fix this?

Comment: What kind of video card do you have and what drivers are you using?  What kind of monitor is this and what kind of connection is it using ( DVI?  DisplayPort? )

Comment: The monitor is Philips 107E6 (CRT) manufactured in2005. connected via vga. I have no idea what "card" is fitted, may just be an on board chip set. The driver is whatever the installation program installed Ubunto 11.10. GUI works fine. System has been running Redhat and Fedorra 10 for ten years.

Comment: 11.10 has reached end of life and is no longer supported.  You need to upgrade.  Also, run `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log, and type "/EDID" to search for lines that mention EDID.  There should be a few screens full of lines describing the monitor.  Edit them into your question.